# Footnote in table* environment

Tags: tex, footnotes

How to add a footnote in table* environment? A solution is provided in the following link:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209802/footnote-in-table-environment

Here in the answer provide in the above link, the footnote appears along with the table notes. Is it possible for the footnote appear as the normal footnote in the footer page?

Answer (score 1):

`table*` is typically associated with a two-column layout, and as a result delayed to not appear on the page it's called. We can use [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to delay execution of the `\footnote` so it'll appear on the same page as the `table*`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage,refcount}
\newcommand{\setfootnotemark}{%
  \refstepcounter{footnote}%
  \footnotemark[\value{footnote}]}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \caption{A table caption}
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    123\setfootnotemark\label{first} & 456 & 
    789\setfootnotemark\label{second} & abc \\
  \end{tabular}
  \afterpage{\footnotetext[\getrefnumber{first}]{First footnote.}
             \footnotetext[\getrefnumber{second}]{Second footnote.}}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[6-10]

\end{document}
```